# CFBundle Version

Tags: iphone, string, version, plist, app-store-connect

I have the following problem with Xcode 4 for an app update:

I changed the Bundle Version to 1.1 as well as the bundle versions strings, short to 1.1 as well as the target version 1.1.

The problem is that on the products folder, where the xxx.app is located, after changing all the version, the .app file does not get modified to the next current version, 1.1 on this case.

I've tried everything and I dont know how to update it to the current version to upload via itunes connect.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project **⇧⌘K** ?

Comment: What do you mean by .app file does not get modified ? Did your version got updated anyway ?
Did you try insert version code check to your appFinishedLoadingWithOptions ? [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] If all is good with your version, maybe the product folder you're looking at isn't the right one (Debug \ Release) ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Actually I've managed yo find a simple solution. My .app file was not updating since I was not running my app on the device, just the simulator. As soon as I ran the app on the development device, the .app file gets updated and now, you can upload to itunes connect with the app loader with no problems (no cfbundle version or any related error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try cleaning the project and deleting the current one from the products folder. Then build again. See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Actually I've managed yo find a simple solution. My .app file was not updating since I was not running my app on the device, just the simulator. As soon as I ran the app on the development device, the .app file gets updated and now, you can upload to itunes connect with the app loader with no problems (no cfbundle version or any related error).